# Apache POI workbook: getName returns null

Tags: java, scala, apache-poi

I am trying to read cells for a xlsx file(provided by user) using Apache POI.

```
val workbook: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel = ...
workbook.getName("cellname")
```

This works fine for one of the input file, but returns null for another file.
Do we need to make any specific changes in input file first to make it compatible with this API?

Comment: Try https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getAllNames-- to see what named ranges the other file actually contains?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fetch data step by step. You can not directly fetch cell without any row/column or any sheet. First when you get workbook you need to check whether it contains any sheet or not. If it contains any sheet then after you should fetch row and after that you can fetch cell. You can refer below sample.

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
System.out.println("Cell value is: " + cell.toString());
```